# issue while implement multithreading with javaStreamingContext context in java

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark

I am facing an issue when I try to stop `JavaStreamingContext` object which is in separate thread. I create a new thread every 5 seconds with `taskExecutor`, and `JavaStreamingContext` is a part of `localthread` variable of every thread.

Whenever I post a rest request from UI then I want to stop `javaStreamingContext` object of that particular thread. I have thread name for each thread which has `javaStreamingContext` object, in rest method object value is shown as `null`.

So If I can not access `threadlocal` variable from outside thread then how to stop `javaStreamingContext` object?

Which approach should I use? Suggest me a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method stopStreamingContext() inside the class of which threads are created in every 5 secs. Inside this method you can stop the streaming context. So whenever you get rest request just call stopStreamingContext() with the thread.

Comment: Yes i tried this, I called stopStreamingContext() from controller but object inside method show  null value. also,also  I write method in same class.

Comment: Can you also add your code to see what you have done exactly ?